# Associating row data with importrange data in a new workbook on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

For our distribution company, we have a sheet that has all of the invoices listed (in reverse chronological order to keep most recent invoices at the top), along with relevant data that our invoicing/accounting person would add. Order date, company name, location, invoice subtotal, taxes, total, outstanding balance, delivery status, etc.

I then have another sheet that pulls this data for our fulfillment and dispatch team. It filters to only the relevant columns (stuff like invoice subtotal/taxes, order date, etc are removed). I do not have it filter by row, so that way it includes ALL of the invoices from the original sheet.

I want to include a "delivery date" column and "assigned driver" column in this spreadsheet, which I have done, but like most people trying to do something similar on here, when a new invoice is added, the manually-entered data on this second sheet doesn't dynamically shift with the imported data, thus causing the rows to misalign.

The formula for the second sheet is `=query(IMPORTRANGE("sheet_id","'Order Tracker'!A:T"),"select Col1, Col3, Col5, Col6, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col19 where Col10 = 'New' OR Col10 = 'Packed' OR Col10 = 'Pending'",1)` I then have columns 10/11 as manual entry columns for driver assigning and delivery date. Unfortunately, as I mentioned, the rows don't stick together so as the dynamic order of the imported columns changes, the static order of the manual columns causes a mismatch.

Is there a way to make this work? Let's say I have the following invoices, with delivery dates and driver manually entered on this second sheet:

```
INV-005 | 10/26 | Frank
INV-004 | 10/27 | Brandon
INV-003 | 10/27 | Frank
INV-002 | 10/26 | Frank
INV-001 | 10/28 | Brandon
```

And then I add a new invoice, INV-006 to the top of the original invoicing spreadsheet. Now the fulfillment spreadsheet will show:

```
INV-006 | 10/26 | Frank
INV-005 | 10/27 | Brandon
INV-004 | 10/27 | Frank
INV-003 | 10/26 | Frank
INV-002 | 10/28 | Brandon
INV-001
```

Instead, I want it to show:

```
INV-006
INV-005 | 10/26 | Frank
INV-004 | 10/27 | Brandon
INV-003 | 10/27 | Frank
INV-002 | 10/26 | Frank
INV-001 | 10/28 | Brandon
```

Comment: Make a test sheet that demonstrates the problem, and post a link. Should be easy to solve. Comment me when done.

Comment: Sure, thank you.

Here is the example invoicing spreadsheet that gets the original data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LU-dSlGqyiKj6xjo5AVvNNdf1pBR26NTuaXZBdLK2Og/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the example fulfillment spreadsheet where they'd add the delivery date and driver assigned to the order: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cU9pF1Me4PLENkUHHnOkaUQlABc6Wqn2agyALsffd6k/edit?usp=sharing

The second sheet needs the static info to stay paired with the dynamic info so that delivery dates and drivers stay associated with the invoice, versus the row it's currently entered on.

Comment: I made copies of these sheets (your links are read only) and it behaves exactly as you say you want it.... I am not seeing the problem you state .. .which by the way is very strange behaviour if its really happening. Make your links read/write Also add an image to your question, showing the before and after situation.

Comment: https://imgur.com/o0eyIZo
Here's the fulfillment sheet. To make this exercise easy to see, I changed the delivery date to the invoice number so you can easily see columns A and L currently match up. So, as long as nothing is added, looks good.

Comment: https://imgur.com/pmuLzmR Here's the invoicing sheet. I add two new invoices and change the status on some of the others (such as going from new to pending, or pending to delivered).

Comment: https://imgur.com/WA3nX2c Now when viewing the fulfillment sheet, you will notice the column L didn't shift down even though new orders were added, and some other orders were removed when they went from pending to delivered (per the filtering rules) but those also didn't change in column L.  So now, Column L and column A do not match up.

Please look at the purple text on each photo for more info if needed.

Comment: Functionality I am desiring is that manually-entered Columns L and Column M are synchronized with the dynamic columns A-K which are imported from another sheet, so that if the order changes in the dynamic columns, the manually-entered columns adjust automatically with them. That way delivery date and driver is actually assigned to a specific invoice rather than an arbitrary row in this spreadsheet.

Comment: OK Thank you I will take a look now and get back if any questions.

Comment: OK I understand your problem exactly. Its interesting and not so easy at first glance! But it will take a day or two between other tasks ...

Comment: awesome I appreciate you spending the time to help!  Look forward to it :)

Answer (score 0):

The script below will do what you need.

When you make a change in your order sheet, the delivery sheet will be updated correctly.
It will update:

1. When you open the delivery sheet
2. If you press a `REFRESH` button on the delivery sheet.

(So not quite as automatically as when using the "`query(IMPORTRANGE..)`" formula).

Here is the code that you will need to install.

```
function onOpen() {
   updateTracker();
}


function updateTracker(){
  // This function is executed when the sheet is opened
  // and also intended to be linked to a REFRESH button to be installed in the sheet
  // The function populates ColA to ColK with data from another sheet
  // Existing data in ColL and ColM has to be preserved, and realigned 
  // with the same invoice numbers in ColA of the new data.

  // Step 1 - read ColA, ColL and ColM of the old data, before repopulating ColA and ColsK
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //var openSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Open Order Tracker");
  var openSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = openSheet.getLastRow(); // locate last row of data
  var invNoArray = openSheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow-1).getValues();   // 1D array of invoices numbers
  var invNoList = {}; 
  for(var row=0; row < invNoArray.length; row++){  // make an "associative array" of invoice numbers
     invNoList[invNoArray[row]] = row;
  }
  // read the delivery dates and driver from this sheet ('Open Order Tracker')
  var driverArray = openSheet.getRange(2,12,lastRow-1,3).getValues();  // 2D array of Delivery Dates and Drivers
  // clear out the old content (not formats or vaidation)
  var currentRange = openSheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,14); 
  currentRange.clearContent();    

  // Step 2 - Read and the data for ColA to ColK from the source sheet
  //------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Simulating this formula
  //=query(IMPORTRANGE("1rm31Zza8fMS2pASIuFvQ0WBBqWb-174lD5VrtAixDjg","'Order Tracker'!A:T"),"select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col5, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, 
  // Col19 where Col10 = 'New' OR Col10 = 'Packed' OR Col10 = 'Pending' OR(Col10 = 'Delivered' AND Col14 > 0.01)",1)

  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1LU-dSlGqyiKj6xjo5AVvNNdf1pBR26NTuaXZBdLK2Og').getSheetByName("Order Tracker");
  var dataRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  var dataValues = dataRange.getValues().filter(function (x) {return x[9]=='New' || x[9] =='Packed' || x[9] == 'Pending' || (x[9] == 'Delivered' && x[13] >=0.01);});

  // Remove columns we dont need.
  var reqValues = [];
  var reqCols=[0,1,2,4,8,9,10,11,12,13,18];    // corresponding to Col1, Col2 etc
  for(var row=0; row<dataValues.length; row++){
    var thisRow = [];
    for (var col=0; col<reqCols.length; col++){
      thisRow.push(dataValues[row][reqCols[col]]);
    }
    // Add placeholders cols for ColL and ColM
    thisRow.push("None");
    thisRow.push("None");
    thisRow.push("None");   // to be removed later
    reqValues.push(thisRow);
  }

  // Step 3 - Populate ColL and ColM - re-aligning the Invoice Numbers
  //------------------------------------------------------------------
  for (var row=0; row < reqValues.length; row++){
    if (invNoList.hasOwnProperty(reqValues[row][0])){
       var invNoIndex= invNoList[reqValues[row][0]];      // locate correct data based on invoice number
       reqValues[row][11] = driverArray[invNoIndex][0];   // fill in Delivery Date
       reqValues[row][12] = driverArray[invNoIndex][1];   // fill in the Driver
       // below line to be removed later
       reqValues[row][13] = driverArray[invNoIndex][2];   // fill in the CrossCheck data
    }  
  }

  //Step 4 -  Copy the reqValues
  //-----------------------------------------------
  var finalRange = openSheet.getRange(2,1,reqValues.length,14);   // openSheet and lastRow should be still valid
  finalRange.setValues(reqValues);

  //Done
}
```

I have tested this in copies of your test sheets and all seems to work OK.
This link is a version of your fulfilment sheet, and has the script and REFRESH button install in Col M: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15ecr9CmXn2YyhMpGTg8VCVf8tTi5GaGrjgmQus9FxWA/edit?usp=sharing

**NOTE to any Google script experts:** I had to make a script version of the original "`query(IMPORTRANGE..)`" formula. This is in step 2. If anyone sees a better way to do this I would be interested to hear. The reason I did this was due to Google script restrictions (as I understand):

1. There is no event following execution of "`query(IMPORTRANGE..)`"
2. If I install the query in script, there is no way to execute it in the script.

Comment: OK here is what I came up with. It will work. I will add some install instructions later today if you are having trouble.