# Align imported data with manual input data in a Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I have two sheets, one with product names (sorted alphabetically) in column A, stock levels in column B.

**Sheet 1**

[image]

The other 2nd sheet with the same products in column A and stock levels in column B but populated by "importrange" but with columns C and D manually populated with customer names.

**Sheet 2**

[image]

What I'd like to do is, if a *new* product is introduced in the 1st sheet and it is positioned alphabetically in (let's say) row 3, then have a new row appear in the 2nd sheet.

**Sheet 2 ideally**

[image]

Currently, if a new product is introduced, the 2nd sheet will show the product and stock level, but the manually entered data in columns C and D will then be out of sync by one row.

**Sheet 2 currently**

[image]

Is there a way of automatically inserting a full row when the new product is imported to the 2nd sheet if I'm using "importrange"?  If there is, can someone please help me here with the formula or code.

Comment: this wont rly be possible unless you introduce some ID system to it. then you can use simple vlookup in arrayformula

Answer (score 1):

Basically what the OP is asking is how to keep the spatial/positional relation between two data sets. One alternative is to adopt the use of "keys" and "foreign keys".

1. Let says that a row represents a **record**.
2. A **key** is an unique value that used to identify a *record*.
3. A **foreign key** is a value added to a *record* to relate it with a *record* from another data set

Applying the above to the question case:

1. On `Sheet 1` add a new column to hold the *key* for each row. When a new record is added the *key* of the other records should not be changed and a new *key* should be assigned to the new record.
2. Create a table of for the values of `Sheet 2`, columns C and D, and add to each record a *key*.

   NOTE: This is the table were you should do the manual input.
3. Create a relation table having two columns one for the *keys* of the *records* on `Sheet 1` and another for the records of `Sheet 2`, Columns C and D.

   <sup>NOTE: I will not discuss here the *arity of a relation* concept as it will make the answer too long.</sup>
4. On `Sheet 2`, use `IMPORTRANGE` to get the values from `Sheet 1`, including the keys for each record.
5. Add a lookup formula (`VLOOKUP` / `INDEX-MATCH`) to get the related records from the table created on step 2 by using the relation table created on step 3.

Related

- [Synchronize independent spreadsheet rows, filled by IMPORTRANGE()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32959875/1595451)
- [Associating row data with importrange data in a new workbook on Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53191966/1595451)

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll have to learn about those things and see how it goes.